# "datetime-local" null input causes MySQL query to fail

Tags: php, mysql, forms, datetime

On my website, hosted on a LAMP stack, I have a simple html POST form with a bunch of inputs, and two *datetime-local* inputs

```
<form>
...
    <input id="PublicationDate" type="datetime-local" name="PublicationDate"/>
    <input id="ExpirationDate" type="datetime-local" name="ExpirationDate"/>
...
</form>
```

These input are matched against two *Datetime* field inside a MySQL table:

```
...
PublicationDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
ExpirationDate DATETIME,
```

Using this php code:

```
// Prepare query
$Query = $this->DB->prepare("
INSERT INTO Article(Title, Subtitle, Author, PublicationDate, ExpirationDate, Body)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, IFNULL(?, NOW()), ?, ?)");
$Query->bindParam(1, $Data["Title"]);
$Query->bindParam(2, $Data["Subtitle"]);
$Query->bindParam(3, $Username);
$Query->bindParam(4, $Data["PublicationDate"]); // <-
$Query->bindParam(5, $Data["ExpirationDate"]); // <-
$Query->bindParam(6, $Data["Body"]);
```

At the beginning, with the same MySQL/Php setup but without the actual fields in the html form, everything worked fine: **PublicationDate** was set to `NOW()` and **ExpirationDate** to `NULL`.

After I added the fields, if I leave those fields empty (in order to have `NOW()` and `NULL` as values) the query fails.

I think this problem is caused by the *datetime-local* inputs, because I have no problem leaving **Subtitle** field empty in order to have the corresponding MySQL row set to `NULL`. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

### EDIT:

The `$Data` array is the `$_POST` array passed as a parameter to a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking one of the values for NULL when you insert it and the other one not at all.

However, when a form is sent in, the values will not be NULL, they will be empty strings so you probably want to set them to NULL if they are empty:

```
$Query->bindParam(4, $Data["PublicationDate"] ?: null);
$Query->bindParam(5, $Data["ExpirationDate"] ?: null);
```

Note that this is very basic, you should add real validation to your fields to check if they match what you are expecting.